# Touch.target vs Event.target

Tags: javascript

In the `touchstart`, `touchmove`, and `touchend` event handlers, under what circumstances will [`Touch.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch/target) be different from [`Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)?

Simple testing suggests that they are always the same, but I may be missing edge cases.

```
function onTouchstart(event: TouchEvent) {
    console.log(event.target === event.changedTouches[0].target);
}
```

Comment: One curiosity is that your snippet is only checking the first changedTouches.  For a touchend, if you drag your touchpoint, the last element in the array could very well not be the starting one

Answer (score 0):

I found a case where it's not the same. When using `capture: true`, `Touch.target` returns a `div` node instead of a `textarea` node when touching a `textarea`. This behavior is rather strange and may be a bug.

```js
window.addEventListener('touchstart', (e) => {
 document.getElementById('x').textContent =  e.changedTouches[0].target.nodeName + '\n' + e.target.nodeName;
}, {capture: true})
```

```css
#x {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="x"></textarea>
```